# C# Script - modify to only write to certain database fields

Tags: c#

I have the following C# script that takes a configured list of elements and writes the values to our database.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public class Script
{
    public static bool ExportData(DataExportArguments args)
    {
        try
        {
            var sqlStringTest = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();


            // SERVER/INSTANCE
            sqlStringTest.DataSource = "SQL Server";
            // DATABASE NAME
            sqlStringTest.InitialCatalog = "Database";
            sqlStringTest.IntegratedSecurity = false;
            sqlStringTest.UserID = "user";
            sqlStringTest.Password = "password";


            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlStringTest.ConnectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                using (IExportReader dataReader = args.Data.GetTable()) //Get the main data table
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read()) // Loop through Export data rows
                    {
                        using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
                        {
                            sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;

                            sqlCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Subjects] (
                            SourceId, 
                            DirectSourceUrl,
                            Identifier,
                            Name,
                            Category)

                             VALUES (
                            @SourceId, 
                            @DirectSourceUrl,
                            @Identifier,
                            @Name,
                            @Category)";

                            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SourceId", dataReader.GetStringValue("SourceId"));
                            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DirectSourceUrl", dataReader.GetStringValue("DirectSourceUrl"));
                            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Identifier", dataReader.GetStringValue("Identifier"));
                            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", dataReader.GetStringValue("Name"));
                            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", dataReader.GetStringValue("Category"));
                            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            args.WriteDebug(exp.ToString(), DebugMessageType.Error);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The issue is that for each configuration to which I attach this script, the fields can be any combination of the above.  For example, in one configuration, I may only be using the `Identifier` and `Name` fields, and in another, all 5 fields, and in yet another maybe just 3 of them.  Therefore I'm having to manually remove the unused fields from the script for each separate configuration I do to avoid getting an error when running the script.

How would I modify this code so that I don't have to manually remove the fields that aren't being used?  It would seem that it would be some form of `IF` and `ELSE IF` statements, but I can't think of how it would be done outside of listing every single possible combination of fields?

Comment: I especially like the comment `/ USE WINDOWS AUTHENTICATION` followed by the opposite :D (We've all done this with comments!)

Comment: Not familiar with `IExportReader` but does it have a method such as `HasField` or something you can use to determine if a field exists in the particular set of data?

Comment: When you don't use them all I assume you want the unused ones to be `null`? Just assign `DBNull.Value` to the parameters for which you don't have a value.

Comment: @Jamiec ha, nice catch!  I've edited the code to take that out.

Comment: @jamiec no IexportReader does not have anything like that as far as I can see.

Comment: @crowcoder, the problem there comes inside my configuration.  I'm configuring different agents for each website we gather data from.  In any given agent, several of the parameters may not exist.  As soon as that scenario occurs, I get an error thrown by the script - it's looking for the parameter to exist within the configuration.  So I can't assign Null to it if it doesn't exist in the configuration.  This is why it seems I need some sort of IF statement.

Comment: Then I don't understand. Is there one database, or one for each agent?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `IExportReader` has some way to determine if a field exists, you could just do something similar to this (Assuming a method `HasField`, and all your fields are nullable):

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SourceId", 
     dataReader.HasField("SourceId") 
           ? dataReader.GetStringValue("SourceId") 
           : DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Some fields are not nullable, but I think that's ok because those fields will always exist in the script.  I need to look further into an alternative to HasField as I'm not sure this exists.